# Exception with liberty profile 18.0.0.1

Tags: java-8, websphere, websphere-liberty

```
[WARNING ] CWWKZ0014W: The application abcEAR could not be started as it could not be found at location abcEAR.ear.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application abcEAR.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application abcEAR. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application abcEAR.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0004E: An exception occurred while starting the application abcEAR. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Any thoughts what could be the reason\fix for this exception?
below is the server.xml. Let me know any more details required.I am quite new so not sure i am providing the correct details.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<server description="new server"> 
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
        <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>       
        <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>       
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>        
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
        <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>      
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="${default.http.port}" httpsPort="${default.https.port}" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>   

    <managedExecutorService jndiName="abc/abc">
    </managedExecutorService>

    <library id="configs">
        <folder dir="${server.config.dir}/config"/>
    </library>

    <logging maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10" traceFileName="trace.log" traceFormat="BASIC" traceSpecification="*=info: JCDI=all: com.ibm.ws.webbeans*=all: org.apache.webbeans*=all"/>

    <include location="serverConfig.xml"/>
    <include location="server-webservices-jndi.xml"/>
    <include location="server-wmq.xml"/>
    <include location="server-datasources.xml"/>

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>

    <logging hideMessage="SRVE9967W"/>

    <cdi12 enableImplicitBeanArchives="false"/>

    <enterpriseApplication id="abcEAR" location="abcEAR.ear" name="abcEAR">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleLib,configs"/>
    </enterpriseApplication>
</server>
```

i see errors in below format for various jar\packages in the log

000000ba org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap                                     I WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from 'package' because of underlying class loading error: Type package not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
W CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the 'package' class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: package
WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path guava.jar can not be found in jar file ... or its parent.

```
------Start of DE processing------  
Exception = java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Source = com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.internal.ApplicationStateManager
probeid = 31
Stack Dump = java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:19)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.loadImplementations(ClassPathLoader.java:145)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPluginImplementation(ClassPathLoader.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPlatformMockMaker(ClassPathLoader.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.<clinit>(ClassPathLoader.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
```

Comment: Can you share your config?

Comment: also can you post the full stack trace? You may need to check the `${server.config.dir}/logs/messages.log` file

Comment: @AndyGuibert any thoughts?

Comment: based on the stack trace the `ConditionalStackTraceFilter` class is failing to initialize which fails the static init of the `MockUtil` class. Why are you including mockito in your application though? I"m guessing you could exclude this dependency from your application and it will still work fine and the error will go away

Comment: I experience the same behaviour with open-liberty 20.0.0.4 and without any mockito dependencies. Any suggestions anybody please?